# Enable to locate qt-sdk package

Tags: qt

I tried to install qt-sdk under ubuntu 18 but it give me error(enable to locate qt-sdk)
how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

The qt-sdk package was a meta package that was not included beyond Ubuntu Xenial.  You can install the packages that were included manually, if you'd like:

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake gdb git libphonon-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libqtwebkit-dev qt4-designer qt4-doc qt4-doc-html qt4-qmake qtcreator qtcreator-doc subversion
```

Comment: I run your command and after it I run again sudo apt-get install qt-sdk but also gave me the same error

Comment: @KemoHassan The qt-sdk package doesn't exist anymore.  The command I posted installs all the packages it used to include.  After running it, you will have all the applications it used to give you.